# oracle intersection with or without distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have following query:

```
select id from t1
intersect
select id from t2
intersect
select id from t3
```

id could be non unique in some tables, so I need to use distinct.

In general what is better:

```
select distinct id from (
select id from t1
intersect
select id from t2
intersect
select id from t3)
```

or

```
select distinct id from t1
intersect
select id from t2 -- here id is unique
intersect
select distinct id from t3
```

Comment: "better" - In what terms? Performance? Just run them both and find out or use explain plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for the `DISTINCT`.  The `INTERSECT` operator automatically produces a distinct set of values.  As you can see in this example, `x` has two rows with an `ID` of 1, `y` only has one row with an `ID` of 1 and the `INTERSECTION` of the two produces just a single row

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (select 1 id from dual union all select 1 from dual),
  2       y as (select 1 id from dual)
  3  select id
  4    from x
  5  intersect
  6  select id
  7*   from y
SQL> /

        ID
----------
         1
```

Even if you take the `INTERSECT` of the two row table with itself, you still get a single row in the output

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (select 1 id from dual union all select 1 from dual)
  2  select id
  3    from x
  4  intersect
  5  select id
  6*   from x
SQL> /

        ID
----------
         1
```